# Can I install a new kernel package using `yum` without updating grub.cfg?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum, grub2

I have 49 rpm packages that I need to install from a local directory.  One of which is `kernel-4.9.135`  Therefore, I want to use `yum` so all dependencies are managed for me (instead of passing `rpm` a list of rpm files).

I also have a very customized `grub.cfg` file that I do not want touched during this process.

I examined the scripts that are run when the kernel package is installed:

```
# rpm -qp --scripts ./kernel-4.9.135-1.x86_64.rpm 
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
if [ -x /sbin/installkernel -a -r /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.135 -a -r /boot/System.map-4.9.135 ]; then
cp /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.135 /boot/.vmlinuz-4.9.135-rpm
cp /boot/System.map-4.9.135 /boot/.System.map-4.9.135-rpm
rm -f /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.135 /boot/System.map-4.9.135
/sbin/installkernel 4.9.135 /boot/.vmlinuz-4.9.135-rpm /boot/.System.map-4.9.135-rpm
rm -f /boot/.vmlinuz-4.9.135-rpm /boot/.System.map-4.9.135-rpm
fi
...
```

`installkernel` contains the following:

```
if [ -n "$cfgLoader" ] && [ -x /sbin/new-kernel-pkg ]; then
if [ -n "$(which dracut 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
    new-kernel-pkg --mkinitrd --dracut --host-only --depmod --install --kernel-name $KERNEL_NAME $KERNEL_VERSION
else
    new-kernel-pkg --mkinitrd --depmod --install --kernel-name $KERNEL_NAME $KERNEL_VERSION
fi
new-kernel-pkg --rpmposttrans --kernel-name $KERNEL_NAME $KERNEL_VERSION
fi
```

And `new-kernel-pkg` uses `grubby` to update my `grub.cfg` file.

Is there some way to tell `yum`, and therefore the kernel rpm, to not do anything to alter `grub.cfg`, while using `yum install` to install all of my packages in one fell swoop?

The workaround is to copy my current`grub.cfg` to the side and copy it back after `yum` is finished but I thought I'd ask the question nonetheless.

Comment: Assuming that CentOS is close to Fedora, you may want to look at the packages that provide /usr/lib/kernel/install.d/ ,  /etc/kernel/install.d/ , and /etc/grub.d . You may be able
to migrate your customizations out of grub.cfg  so that kernel updates create a new grub.cfg that includes your customizations.

Comment: You're right and I agree.  The correct way to do this is to move my customizations out of `grub.cfg`.  That activity is in progress and will happen eventually.  The immediate goal here is to satisfy my curiosity about being able to alter the default "workflow" of a `yum install` in this particular instance.  I do have a work-around that I'm okay using for now.  Thanks for the feedback.  FYI, in CentOS, most of the customization files are in `/etc/grub.d/` and `/etc/default/grub` as @yurij mentions below.

Answer (score 2):

Your trick with `grub.conf` is working solution. Also you can apply one of the next approaches:

1. Download kernel rpm package with `yumdownloader` and install kernel package with `--noscripts` parameter to ignore scripts which configure package by running `prerun`, `postrun` ... scripts during package are being configured. There is no way to tell `--noscripts` to `yum` directly.
2. If you want persistent `grub.conf` after any new kernel installation via `yum` you should copy your current `grub.conf` menu entries that belong to your kernel to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and unset exec permissions (`chmod a-x`) from `/etc/grub.d/30_probe_os` (this script scans `/boot` directory for new kernels and initramfs files and generates menuentries for `grub.conf`). After this step all attempts of generate `grub.conf` bu running `grub2-mkconfig` will return only menu entries that contains in your custom configuration file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.